# Duplicate Images in Google Image Search

Tags: android, google-image-search

I am using google image search in my App, and I need only 5 images from google. But sometimes I am getting 2-3 duplicate images. Is there any way to get unique images?

Using following query : 
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key="API_KEY"&q=&searchType=image&num=5&imgSize=large

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could - it's twisted - use the Google Images inverted search :
You get the first image, search the web for other images like this one, stock all the top (most referenced) links in a list, and exclude those from your search (with minus symbol and between double quotes) when you want to get the second image.

Hope this helps

Comment: but the images I get have different URL but same image. Will this help for this condition?